# Clearing browser cache with Selenium

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, web-testing

I've been using the Ruby selenium-webdriver gem to perform some testing on a web app at work. One thing that would be great would be the ability to programmatically clear the browsers cache before performing timed page loads etc but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Does anyone know if is there a simple way of doing this with the gem?

Comment: does selenium actually cache anything?

Comment: I'm not sure but I assumed that the browser it controls would be caching.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on jacksparrow007's answer, but in Ruby Selenium, his suggestion could be coded as:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.cache.disk.enable'] = false
profile['browser.cache.memory.enable'] = false
profile['browser.cache.offline.enable'] = false
profile['network.http.use-cache'] = false
Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps!

```
@driver.manage.delete_all_cookies
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by making a custom firefox profile and then telling your driver to use that. check [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=40) out.